COD 4 multiplayer error "exe_err_not_found_configure_mp.csv"
In Call of Duty 4 Multiplayer I get the following error when I open the application:

EXE_ERR_NOT_FOUND_configure_mp.csv

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Hi Usitha, is this about a legal version of the game?

yes.this is new version of call of duty modern wafare multiplayer. 1.6 and 1.7 patches are downloaded

I was asking because this problem seems to occur mostly (exclusively?) with pirated games. What have you tried so far? Reinstalling, updating video card drivers, updating DirectX?

if you can send me a link of call of duty modern wafare multiplayer setup and patches

I can't (and won't), and you should be able to download them anyway, right? Did you try reinstalling the game?

You should also add the tag for the plaftorm you are playing on, this is PC I suppose
